# getting value from json string php

Tags: php, json

```
$srt = '{"list":"[{"BP":"94"},{"BP":"99"},{"BP":"85"},{"BP":"84"},{"BP":"95"}]"}'
```

I want  to decode  this  json  object ,  in

```
$json_arr2 = array();
$json_arr2  = json_decode($srt,true);

var_dump($json_arr2);
```

It gives  null, please  help me  to  get  value  from   this  string  in php.

Comment: Someone named Jason might not like values taken from them.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON isn't valid.

Try:

```
$srt = '{"list":[{"BP":"94"},{"BP":"99"},{"BP":"85"},{"BP":"84"},{"BP":"95"}]}';
```

http://www.jsonlint.com might help you in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to check how your json look like.

There should be no **"** before **[** and after **]**