# Getting Value from Json Strings

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, foreach

Well this was a 7 years old question here and I need the answer from this thread no satisfying answer was given: [getting value from json string php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737478/getting-value-from-json-string-php) someone should kindly assist as my code is of this format:

after json_decode()

var_dump gave this as output:

```
 String(384) “{“data:{“foo”: bar, “foo1”: “bar1”, “foo2”: bar2, }}
```

Note that bar is int, bar1 string etc.

How can I get "foo1": "bar1" from this string; generally how can I get values from setups like this in PHP?

Comment: Are you sure you called `var_dump(json_decode($value))`?

Comment: It won't work with th crazy wacked out quotes `““` And the fact that the first `{` is quoted.  This is not valid JSON.

Comment: Exactly I checked it with <http://www.jsonlint.com > and it says invalid json and I copied the whole data and checked it on it..the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get your JSON object, you can access `foo1` simply like this:

```
$str = '{"data": {"foo": bar, "foo1": "bar1", "foo2": bar2}}';
$json = json_decode($str);
echo $json->data->foo1;
```

Comment: Okay Let me try this out.

Comment: wow this worked: I was doing something like this $var =var_dump(json_decode($data true)); and it was giving string. I had to remove it from the variable and remove true. But I am not sure why it doesn't work that way. I appreciate your input.

Comment: I tried yesterday but they said I am just new to the site. It is recorded but the public can't see it :(